# How to track my custom JS Chatbot installed on many domains

Tags: javascript, analytics, chatbot

I developed a chatbot in JS. We are going to deploy it massively on multiple websites.

How can i track custom events for every client and most important how to embed my analytics tracking code and identify end-users's client events ?

FYI : Chatbot doesn't use web socket and is not a real time, it parses only a tree, show node and keep answers until the end.

1- Is embedding Universal Analytics (ga.js) will work ?

2- Is it worthi it using some other analytics tools like : [botanalytics](https://botanalytics.co) or [Botmetrics](https://www.getbotmetrics.com/)

Thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

[Chatbase](http://chatbase.com) is platform-agnostic/includes rich filters and can be used for exactly this requirement.

Comment: Very helpful !! i will check it and give some feed backs for history :) Thanks !